# C# WPF - GridLength GridUnitType.Auto

Tags: c#, wpf, gridlength

Can anyone explain the difference between using:

```
 GridLength length = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto)
```

and

```
 GridLength length = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
```

My limited knowledge of this leads me to believing these would both be identical solutions due to auto being as it states..."auto", therefore making the double value redundant.

Most examples I have seen show the `GridUnitType.Auto` being preceded with 1 rather than 0, but it seems to me that either option works the same?

Is this the case or can anyone shed some light on if/how these are different

Comment: i think you should directly use GridLength.Auto

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think your understanding is correct, when the value `GridUnitType.Auto` is used, the first value passed to the constructor is redundant, as the size will be determined by the content object.

It somewhat makes sense in the context of the `GridLength` structure constructor to retain this parameter (even though it's not used in this instance), as it allows the second parameter type to contain values that describe the all available states of `GridUnitType`.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx):

The enumerated type `GridUnitType` can contain the following values:

```
Auto   - The size is determined by the size properties of the content object. 
Pixel  - The value is expressed as a pixel. 
Star   - The value is expressed as a weighted proportion of available space.
```

So really, the first parameter is only relevant when the second parameter is set to `GridUnitType.Pixel` or `GridUnitType.Star`.

It wouldn't work neatly other way around e.g. if you tried to have constructor that accepted 1 parameter as a `GridUnitType`, and only required the second parameter if you used `Pixel` or `Star`.

This way round, you get the benefit of having a 1 parameter constructor that accepts a double without specifying the additional type. Although it does have the cost of a potentially odd looking two parameter constructor when using `Auto` (as in your example).

Comment: Thanks, I also understand it would be relevant when using

`GridUnitType.Star` as

`GridLength oneThird = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);` and
`GridLength twoThirds = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);`

as the the space would be weighted giving the second GridLenth double the space of the first?

Comment: You're correct, I got a tad carried away with formatting and didn't properly proof what I'd written (thanks Clemens!).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there is also a static property `GridLength.Auto` which looks nicer than the constructor initialisation.